# PHP: insert query result inside array elements

Tags: php, arrays

```
function standard_deviation_population ($a)
{
  //variable and initializations
  $the_standard_deviation = 0.0;
  $the_variance = 0.0;
  $the_mean = 0.0;
  $the_array_sum = array_sum($a); //sum the elements
  $number_elements = count($a); //count the number of elements

  //calculate the mean
  $the_mean = $the_array_sum / $number_elements;

  //calculate the variance
  for ($i = 0; $i < $number_elements; $i++)
  {
    //sum the array
    $the_variance = $the_variance + ($a[$i] - $the_mean) * ($a[$i] - $the_mean);
  }

  $the_variance = $the_variance / $number_elements;

  //calculate the standard deviation
  $the_standard_deviation = pow( $the_variance, 0.5);

  //return the variance
  return $the_standard_deviation;
}

$query_question = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM question order by s_id");
$QuestionDimArray = array();
while ($data_question = mysqli_fetch_array($query_question))
{
    $QuestionDimArray []= $data_question['q_id'];
}
$a = array($QuestionDimArray());
$standard_deviation = standard_deviation_population ($a);
echo "standard_deviation =" .$standard_deviation;
```

How to store database value into

```
$variable = array([database values here]);
```

for example, with defined values (1,2,3)

```
$a = array(1,2,3);

$standard_deviation = standard_deviation_population ($a);

echo "standard_deviation =" .$standard_deviation;
```

that returns,
standard_deviation = 0.81649658092773

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: not my first language sorry

Comment: Don't know what u expecting???

Comment: Please post code as text, NOT an image and not an offsite image

Comment: Don't know what kind of code inside the standard_deviation_population() function

Comment: **So what does the function `standard_deviation_population()` do** That is where the work is being done, not in the code you are showing us

Comment: Done adding the function in question.

Comment: I just want to know how to put the values from database into $a = array();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not good idea to calculate the standard deviation this way. Database systems has a built-in functions for standard deviation. You can get it in one query, something like this: `SELECT STDDEV_POP(q_id) FROM question`.

In your code the `$QuestionDimArray` is already an array. You could just `$standard_deviation = standard_deviation_population ($QuestionDimArray);`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but if I understand well you want put all your database result in $variable ?

```
$query_question = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM question order by s_id");
$QuestionDimArray = array();
while ($data_question = mysqli_fetch_array($query_question)) {
   $QuestionDimArray []= $data_question['q_id'];
   /* if you want the full data line from your query use. It depends your implementation.
      You will have an 2d array
      [['col1' => 'val_line_1_1', 'col2'=> 'val_line_1_2',...],...,['col1' => 'val_line_n_1', 'col2'=> 'val_line_n_2',...]]
   $QuestionDimArray []= $data_question;
   */
}
// $a = array($QuestionDimArray()); unless you want copy the array this line is useless. Event worst its wrong
$standard_deviation = standard_deviation_population ($questionDimArray);
echo "standard_deviation =" .$standard_deviation;
```